# How to find distinct value with count of other array inside dhe document in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to get distinct categoryCode and categoryName while this document also contains list of accessories I want to count of this accessories in the response.

Sample data:

```
[
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "accessories":[{"a_id":1},{"a_id":2}]
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCod2",
      "categoryName":"categoryName2",
      "accessories":[{"a_id":1},{"a_id":2},{"a_id":3}]
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryNam1",
      "accessories":[{"a_id":1},{"a_id":2}]
   }
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "accessoriesCount":2
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCod2",
      "categoryName":"categoryName2",
      "accessoriesCount":3
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/q6AZOaTwo5a

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        categoryCode: "$categoryCode",
        "categoryName": "$categoryName"
      },
      "accessories": {
        "$addToSet": "$accessories"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      categoryCode: "$_id.categoryCode",
      categoryName: "$_id.categoryName",
      accessoriesCount: {
        $size: "$accessories"
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Query

- group to have the distinct values
- `$push` the accesories arrays (we dont have `$concat` accumulator)
- reduce those arrays to union them, keep only the distinct members, and take the count.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PXjEp5z-Uxm)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "categoryCode": "$categoryCode",
        "categoryName": "$categoryName"
      },
      "accessories": {
        "$push": "$accessories"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "accessoriesCount": {
        "$size": {
          "$reduce": {
            "input": "$accessories",
            "initialValue": [],
            "in": {
              "$setUnion": [
                "$$value",
                "$$this"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "categoryCode": "$_id.categoryCode",
      "categoryName": "$_id.categoryName",
      "accessoriesCount": "$accessoriesCount"
    }
  }
])
```